# Quarkus Devservice for Oracle Database is not working

Tags: oracle, quarkus

I am working on Quarkus Microservice application in which trying to use Quarkus Devservice to start Oracle DB with below configuration in application.yml file. But it's throwing exception.

**application.yml:**

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: oracle
    username: root
    password: password
    devservices:
      image-name: oracle
```

**Exception:**

```
   Failed to load steps from class 'io.quarkus.devservice.oracle.deployment.OracleDevServicesProcessoer'
```